# TFS 2012 error: Unrecognized attribute requestValidationMode in web.config after windows update patches

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS 2012 server running on Windows Server 2008 R2. For the past several months, whenever there are windows patches, the TFS 2012 server will not be functioning correctly. The error message is: Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode' in web.config.

I checked my backup files for the web.config, the attribute was there a long time ago. I saw that 'requestValidtionMode' is for .NET runtime 4.0, not runtime 2.0. But I can see my ApplicationPool is always running under 2.0. If I changed the application pool to run under .NET runtime 4.0, the TFS application can't find many modules.

For the last couple times, I fixed the problem by upgrading my TFS server. But it is now at TFS 2012 Update 4 and I can't upgrade it anymore. I tried to run the repair of the installation, but it couldn't solve the problem.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you see the error message? Could you check the event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is useful messages? Also, check [this case](https://forums.asp.net/t/2011777.aspx?Unrecognized+attribute+requestValidationMode+) to see whether it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error, and what happened to me is that some windows updates related to .Net framework 4.0 had failed, and it appears to have downgraded the AppPool in IIS to .Net 2.0 - which was having difficulties to process those attributes.  Once I got the windows updates to install, and got the AppPool set back to 4.0, all the troubles went away.